# Discord Bot don't send dm messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using this code

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message)=>{
  if (message.content.includes("secret message")) {
    message.author.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
  }
});
```

And as a result of it I get an error, what is wrong?

```json
{
  "requestBody": {
    "files": [],
    "json": {
      "content": undefined,
      "tts": false,
      "nonce": undefined,
      "embeds": [
        {
          "title": "Gizli Komutlara Hoşgeldiniz!",
          "color": 15418782,
          "description": "Öncelikle prefiximiz \"g.\" \n\n g.duyuru: general chatine mesaj için kullanılır. g.duyuru mesaj yazıı \n g.reveal: Her hafta pazar gizli komutlar listesini açıklamada buluna \n g.seskanallarındansg: Ses kanallarında bulunan tüm kullanıcıları dis",
          "author": {
            "name": "Frisado1",
            "url": undefined,
            "icon_url": undefined
          },
          "image": {
            "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1056502145253384213/12134 3d184f8e38c1916&"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-03-04T15:15:26.288Z",
  "footer": {
    "text": "Made by goktug_yldz",
    "icon_url": undefined
  },
  "components": undefined,
  "username": undefined,
  "avatar_url": undefined,
  "allowed_mentions": undefined,
  "flags": undefined,
  "message_reference": undefined,
  "attachments": undefined,
  "sticker_ids": undefined,
  "thread_name": undefined,
  "rawError": {
    "message": "Cannot send messages to this user",
    "code": 50007
  },
  "code": 50007,
  "status": 403,
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1213210223276457994/messages"
}
```

I want the bot to send this message embed to the user's DM

Comment: Have you google "Discord error 50007"? That is giving me some results

Comment: yes and I couldn't find anything about how to solve this error

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as an image. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Is the user in the server

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with your code.
It is happening because your discord account's DM is closed. And when your DM is closed no one can message you so can the bot.

Unlock your Discord Dm from

`Settings -> Privacy & Safety` then enable `Allow direct messages from server members`

This should fix your issue and consider adding an error handler in your code like this:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message)=>{
  if (message.content.includes("secret message")) {
     try {
       await message.author.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
    } catch(error) {
       await message.reply({ content: "Cannot send the message as your dm is closed" });
    }
  }
});
```